# Examples of high MaxStartups or Max Session in use

Tags: ssh, sshd, github

I run a bitbucket instance where there are 4000s+ unique users per day, however sometimes users receive the `error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` - the current config for MaxStartups and MaxSessions:

```
MaxStartups 100

MaxSessions 20:50:100
```

Could the MaxSessions / MaxStartups be too low of the amount for the users in use?

Eg, could that be

```
MaxStartups 500

MaxSessions 100:400:500
```

If so, does anyone have any examples of their config in a higher user environment or could that be a limiting factor?

Every other aspect of configuration seems fine.